# Get three element from database using mysql_fetch_array and php

Tags: php, mysql

I've got in my database for example 7 columns with 5 rows (ID,title , date,text,img), I want to get title and img from the last three colums and i did this:

```
<?$queryT = "SELECT * FROM mainpage ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT  1";
        $resultT = mysql_query($queryT) or die(mysql_error()."[".$queryT."]");
        $queryI = "SELECT * FROM mainpage ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT  1";
        $resultI = mysql_query($queryI) or die(mysql_error()."[".$queryI."]");
    ?>

        <?while ($rowT = mysql_fetch_array($resultT, MYSQL_BOTH)){
            while ($rowI = mysql_fetch_array($resultI, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        ?>
        <ul class="bjqs">
          <li><img src="<?php echo $rowI["IMG"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $rowT["TITLE"]; ?>" class="siderNews"></li>
          <li><img src="<?php echo $rowI["IMG"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $rowT["TITLE"]; ?>" class="siderNews"></li>
          <li><img src="<?php echo $rowI["IMG"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $rowT["TITLE"]; ?>" class="siderNews"></li>
        </ul>

        <?
        }
        }
        ?>
```

but it's printing me , three times the information from the last column only. I use and print that information in a slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $queryT = "SELECT * FROM mainpage ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT  0,3";
    $resultT = mysql_query($queryT) or die(mysql_error()."[".$queryT."]");
?>

<ul class="bjqs">
   <?php while($rowT = mysql_fetch_array($resultT, MYSQL_BOTH)) { ?>
      <li><img src="<?php echo $rowT["IMG"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $rowT["TITLE"]; ?>"        class="siderNews"></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: oooo god bless you , thanks a lot ... i was hitting my head on the computer for two days

Answer (score 0):

try this once

```
 <?php $queryT = "SELECT * FROM mainpage ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT  0,3";
    $resultT = mysql_query($queryT) or die(mysql_error()."[".$queryT."]");

?>
    <ul class="bjqs">
  <?php while ($rowT = mysql_fetch_array($resultT, MYSQL_BOTH)){     
    ?>
  <li><img src="<?php echo $rowI["IMG"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $rowT["TITLE"]; ?>" class="siderNews"></li>
   <?

    }?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Do not use short tags. They are deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: thank, but it's not working now doesn't print nothing. Also the the slider doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

You have a while statement inside another while statement. Meaning as it iterates through one while, it will iterate through the other one, depending on how many results it gets.

```
<?PHP
$queryT = "SELECT * FROM mainpage ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3";
$resultT = mysql_query($queryT) or die(mysql_error() . "[" . $queryT . "]");
?>

<?PHP
while ($rowT = mysql_fetch_array($resultT, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    ?>
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li><img src="<?PHP echo $rowT["IMG"]; ?>" title="<?PHP echo $rowT["TITLE"]; ?>" class="siderNews"></li>
    </ul>

    <?PHP
}
?>
```